# WCF service hosted in IIS 7 - binding configuration settings are ignored

Tags: wcf, iis-7, nettcpbinding, was

I have a WCF service operation that accepts a byte array as part of its data contract. The service is only exposed internally (not to the internet), and I want to increase the quotas to allow for a 10MB byte array.

The service is hosted in IIS7. When I try to send a byte array over the default length, I get the following exception message:

> There was an error deserializing the object of type
>   MyService.ServiceContracts.Data. The maximum array length quota
>   (16384) has been exceeded while reading XML data. This quota may be
>   increased by changing the MaxArrayLength property on the
>   XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas object used when creating the XML reader.
>   Line 1, position 22991.

Here's the configuration:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="largeBinaryBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="10001000" 
                 maxBufferPoolSize="80008000" maxBufferSize="10001000"
                 receiveTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" 
                 closeTimeout="00:01:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00">
            <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="10000000" />
        </binding>
    </netTcpBinding>

    <services>
        <service name="MyService">
            <endpoint binding="netTcpBinding"
                      bindingConfiguration="largeBinaryBinding"
                      bindingNamespace="http://my.services.co.uk/MyService"
                      contract="Services.MyService.ServiceContracts.IMyService" />
        </service>
    </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

So my configuration allows for larger messages, but IIS seems to be ignoring this - how do I stop this and allow large messages through?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Again, just after I post a question I discover the answer!

When using WAS, you need to specify the full class name of the service in the configuration's service name. So in my example, I had my service implementation class called `MyService`, in the namespace `Services`. Therefore, in the configuration, I need

```
<service name="Services.MyService">
   ...
```

Otherwise IIS silently ignores your carefully crafted configuration! How convenient.